# How to share displays through WiFi

Tags: 13.04, wireless, display

I have an LG Smart TV with a WiFi dongle and a notebook with Ubuntu 13.04.

I'd like to use my TV as a monitor but by WiFi.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google's Chromecast may be a good way to do this, although it is limited in what it can display... It's only $35 US, and works quite well... You may find this interesting, especially in regards to HDMI video over WiFi: http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/the-best-wireless-hdmi-video-transmitter/